# Trying to view ir/image raw from Xtion Pro crashes camera nodelet

Tags: openni, xtion, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all! When trying to view the raw ir image from the Xtion Pro (Ubuntu/Diamondback using openni_camera_unstable):

roslaunch openni_camera_unstable openni.launch
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/ir/image_raw

I get:

/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/common/nodelet/bin/nodelet: symbol lookup error: /home/prp/ros/prp/openni_kinect/openni_camera_unstable/lib/libopenni_nodelet.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK14openni_wrapper7IRImage7fillRawEjjPtj
[camera_nodelet_manager-1] process has died [pid 17721, exit code 127].

The last entry in the log is:

Connection: Creating TransportSubscriberLink for topic [/camera/ir/image_raw] connected to [callerid=[/image_view_1311275454656139276] address=[TCPROS connection to [127.0.1.1:47969 on socket 31]]]

Is this a problem, or am I just trying to do something I shouldn't be doing? Otherwise, things seem be working fine and I can view the point clouds using rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10686/trying-to-view-ir/image-raw-from-xtion-pro-crashes-camera-nodelet/) by [prp](https://answers.ros.org/users/706/prp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2011-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should be fixed in recent releases.

I've just verified that I can use my Xtion Pro with the new ROS Electric release, following the instructions at http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0